# No link to the test results in the Build Results reports in TFS 2008

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2008, tfsbuild

Is there a way to display the test results on the build results page returned by Build.aspx page? Because right now you only get to see the total number of tests and the number of failed and passed tests as in the sample:

Result details for Any CPU/Debug  0 errors, 90 warnings, 12 tests total, 4 tests passed, 8 tests failed 
Errors and Warnings: 0 errors, 90 warnings 
Test Results: 1 test runs completed, 12 tests total, 4 passed, 8 failed 
Test Run Run By Total Passed Failed
TFSBUILD@TFB 2008-01-15 15:23:42_Any CPU_Debug PROJECTA\TFSBUILD 12 4 8

Furthermore in the Visual Studio 2008 GUI the Test Run can be opened because it is a link point to the .trx file in the TestResults subfolder of the \Build\ folder but the Build.aspx page does not show this as a link. Better would be maybe if you would get to see the list of tests and for each whether it passed or not.

I am saying this because we use the Team Foundation Build Notification Tool from the TFS 2008 Power Tools and right now you see that a build failed or partially succeeded but you cannot see the test list.

Answer (score 1):

It's been one of my constant frustrations with VSTS that, out of the box, test results are not visible to **anyone** who does not have the VS Test SKU.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446/how-do-i-format-visual-studio-test-results-file-trx-into-a-more-readable-forma) on how to at least get .trx files into HTML.

As for the build summary itself, last I heard there is no way to customize this, nor are there plans to allow doing so in the future.  One could do the transformation of the .trx test results file, and post the HTML results to a known location, though.