# How to convert a ".trx" file to HTML

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, file-conversion, trx

I generate my tests suite with `vstest.console` with VS 2012 and get my test result in a `.trx` format file.

I want to convert this result file toHTML. I used the `trx2html` tool. But I get an error when I run it.

> Error :  System.IO.FileLoadException
>
> trx2html.exe C:\Users...\Desktop\result.trx

How can I solve this problem?
Do other tools exist that allow converting a `.trx` file to `html` or `pdf` ?

One more thing, I'm using orderedtest so my trx file come from orderedtest created by VS2012

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with trx2html tool and vs2012, so I suppose you have the latest version from Codeplex (http://trx2html.codeplex.com/).

Although obviating the error, this question may be useful for you:

[How do I format Visual Studio Test results file (.trx) into a more readable format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446/how-do-i-format-visual-studio-test-results-file-trx-into-a-more-readable-form)

Comment: I used the latest version, but I always get this error. This topic answer to how Format, I just want one tool to convert it. But nothing works properly.